# Ubuntu not mounting any external drive

Tags: mount

It's not mounting anything, I've tried many USB drives, memory cards etc. So I can't backup my data, its more than 10GB so I'm not thinking of any online backup. At the boot time, while checking for errors in drives, an error message occurs - mnt/sdb not found. User not found
And when I mount the usb drive after the boot it says-'Operation not successful' (automatic mounting). When I change its mount settings, it says "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb"
When I saw the usb folder inside the mnt folder, it was empty. 
If anyone knows which path to choose in the disk drive settings or the command of manual mounting it would be very helpful

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubunutu! Please try to describe your problem in more detail to get an answer. Edit your question and add information like what commands you used to mount your drives and what were the exact error messages you got upon entering them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution, but seems to be software error. My drive have only 318GB - i take it from eeePC netbook and buy usb sata box for it, so I can plug as external drive later. Actually I buy two boxes - one fron eBuy, other - in local market. First one let me see my drive once, after several plug/unplug - box died, and not responced anymore (power light blinks once). I notice, that wire which was in complect, was with two USB A and one USB B on other side, but box has only USB A port. Then I buyed second one and story repeats simulary, but now I have box with USB B port :) In store seller says to me, that one USB port needed to connect drive to PC, that power supply is enought for such drive. And he was right! At least for ~24h of time when externel drive was connected to the computer. :)

The boxes, whitch I buy from eBuy and local stock are same. They looks indentical, except USB port - one has USB B ( **GEMBIRD (R)** ) other - USB A ( unnamed **2.5" SATA EXTERNAL CASE** with sereal ATA and USB 2.0 logos ).

So, my solution is simple - plug in with additional USB power supply (use both USB A cables to connect your drive)

P.S. Why first time I was able to connect my drive with only one cable, but after while - only with two cables, kernel bug?